# Can I use "Config" object with boto3 resource?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I would like to use a boto3 config object to configure connection timeout and other attributes when interacting with DynamoDB through boto3. I have already written my code using a boto3 resource, and all the examples I have been able to find leverage a boto3 client instead when using a config object.

Is it possible to use a config object with a boto3 resource, and if not, why?

Comment: Create a session and then use the session to create the resource e.g. `ddb = session.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region)` and then `table = ddb.Table(table_name)`? More [here](https://ben11kehoe.medium.com/boto3-sessions-and-why-you-should-use-them-9b094eb5ca8e).

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say config object?

Answer (score 3):

I learned that a boto3 resource objects does in fact accept a parameter for a config object. So I was able to define a config object in my wrapper class:

```
from botocore.config import Config
```

..

```
self.config = Config(
                    connect_timeout = 1,
                    read_timeout =1
                )
```

And then later do this:

```
self.dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', config = self.config)
```